# Javascript plugin creation

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to create a plugin called 'myPlugin'. Which method should I use and what is the difference between these two methods? Please tell me the advantages too. I am from designing background and not much programming knowledge.

```
 var myPlugin = {
     myId:"testId",        
     create:function(){},
     destroy:function(){}
}
```

OR

```
function myPlugin() {
this.myId = "testId";
this.create = function(){};
this.destroy = function(){};
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method creates a *singleton* object, stored in a variable called `myPlugin`. Only one instance of the "plugin" exists in this form. If you know you will only need one instance, this approach is a good choice. You can also extend its capabilities to allow for both public and "private" properties by using the [Module Pattern](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/).

The second method defines an object constructor function, which will allow you to make multiple instances of the object using the `new` keyword. This will allow you to use as many copies of the object as you might need, and sets you up with the ability to add onto the object using its `prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like:

```
function myPlugin () {
    this.myId = "testId";
    this.create = createFunction;
    this.destroy = destroyFunction;
}
function createFunction() {
    alert('createFunction() called');
}
function destryFunction() {
    alert('destroyFunction() called');
}

my plugin = new myPlugin();
```